# What is the hp_accel module, and what does it do?

Tags: kernel-modules

I was looking at what modules were loaded the other day on my laptop and I was wondering what the hp_accel module does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the kernel sources](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=drivers/platform/x86/hp_accel.c;hb=HEAD):

```
hp_accel.c - Interface between LIS3LV02DL driver and HP ACPI BIOS
```

Looks like [LIS3LV02DL](http://pl.mouser.com/search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=%252bFmDY/mH7IZy7lzgGBC5mw==) is an accelerometer board.

Comment: lol I was writing my answer and had to go afk - yours was more detailed though :P

Answer (score 2):

You have an HP accelerometer on your PC model LIS3LV02Dx. This device is for your hard disk. In case of free fall it deactivates the disk in order to protect it.

hp_accel: is Glue between LIS3LV02Dx and HP ACPI BIOS and support for disk protection LED.

When there is a free fall or the accelerometer detects the possibility of damage the hard disk the led will change to red and protect it.

If you have one of the latest versions of Ubuntu the system will activate the kernel module lis3lv02d, that is a driver to use the accelerometer as a joystick. So you can play pinball with your laptop.

lis3lv02d: ST LIS3LV02Dx three-axis digital accelerometer driver

You can use the program jstest-gtk to see that when you move your laptop the values of the axis change as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this is for your HP accelerometer.

I have an HP as well with the same feature (and module loaded).